# system() not working as expected with %ERRORLEVEL%

Tags: c, windows, winapi, networking, cmd

I was trying to find a way to see if a host is alive in C on Windows so I ran system with a ping command and then ran system checking %ERRORLEVEL% but it was always showing 0 even if the host was not reachable.

```
system("ping -w 1000 -n 1 192.168.0.4 | findstr /r /c:\"[0-9] *ms\"");
system("echo %ERRORLEVEL%");
```

Furthermore even I system call something that will defintely fail like:

```
system("call dir");
system("echo %ERRORLEVEL%");
```

%ERRORLEVEL% will still print a 0. Even after the call command failed with:

"'poop' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file".

Moreover I noticed some strange behavior that if I tried to see the %ERRORLEVEL% on the same command as the ping in cmd:

```
ping -n 1 192.168.0.1 | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms" & echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

it would always return the previous %ERRORLEVEL%. For example if i pinged 192.168.0.1 which is reachable I would 1 or 0 depending on my last command. But if I ran the command again I would get 0. Now if I checked 192.168.0.4 which is not reachable I would get 0. But if I checked it again I would get 1.

Can anyone help me possibly find a better way to see if hosts are available or find out what im doing wrong with %ERRORLEVEL% and system()?

Comment: you can use [nmap](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html) for host discovery if 3rd party tools are an option. It is ported to Windows. It can do ping sweeps, port scans... just about anything you could want to do.

Comment: My goal was to make my own tool and not use a pre-made tool

Comment: @JustinBraham> in that case use the appropriate API, do not spawn another program. That's prone to failure, very slow and consumes a lot of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to `system()` spawns a new instance of `cmd.exe`, that is why you are losing the error info.  The return value of `system()` is defined as an "implementation-defined value", but it is *usually* the exit code of the spawned process.

Or, you can use [`CreateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) to run `ping` directly, and use [`GetExitCodeProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189.aspx) to get its exit code.

Or, simply don't run `ping` at all.  You can use [`IcmpSendEcho()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050.aspx) (or related function) instead.

Answer (score 1):

With each `system` call you spawn a new `cmd` shell. So the exit value of a program run in a previous shell (`system` call) is not available in the next one.

To get the exit value and use it, make a batch job that you run with the system command. All commands in the batch job (`.bat`) are executed in the same shell so the exit value of the previous command is available for your `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

The WinAPI function [IcmpSendEcho](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050(v=vs.85).aspx) will check if a host is alive. You can see if the host received the request when IcmpSendEcho is finished and the response is stored in the [ICMP_ECHO_REPLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366053(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. Check the Status member for details about the request.